# Waiting for function to complete in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following situation: When my app first runs, in the .run function, I issue an http request to get a list of "monitors". Once received, it populates a monitors array in a service. This service is used by many controllers to share data. This service is called ZMDataModel. ZMDataModel offers a function called isMonitorsLoaded(). When this returns 1, I know the monitors array is populated (and that the http call is complete)

Now, I have a page called Monitors, the controller for which is zmApp.MonitorCtrl, shown below. What I need to do, in this MonitorCtrl is to  basically, right at the start, do an equivalent of:

```
while (ZMData.isMonitorsLoaded()!=1);
```

Now I obviously can't do that because it locks my browser up, and the browser never gets a chance to set isMonitorLoaded to 1 in the first place, so it becomes an endless loop.

I understand I need to put in a timeout somehow, but can't quite follow what I need to do in the controller. My controller code is below:

```html
angular.module('zmApp.controllers').controller('zmApp.MonitorCtrl', function($scope, $http, ZMHttpFactory, ZMDataModel) {

  $scope.monitors = [];
  
            
  console.log("***Waiting for Monitors to load before I proceed");
  // I can't do a tight loop waiting for ZMDataModel.isMonitorsLoaded
  // so some timeout?
  
    $scope.monitors = ZMDataModel.getMonitors();
    
    console.log("I GOT " + $scope.monitors);


$scope.doRefresh = function() {
    console.log("***Pull to Refresh");                                           
    $scope.monitors = [];
    ZMHttpFactory.getMonitors().then(function(data) {
    $scope.monitors = data;
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    console.log("I GOT " + $scope.monitors);
  });
};
                                               
});
```

Comment: Does it have to be like this for some design reason? I am wondering why not use a route resolve to load the data and inject it in to the controller

Comment: John, it doesn't. I'm new to AngularJS - can you throw some light on how to use route resolve to load the data and only then load this view? Sounds like what I am looking for

Comment: look here http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx

Comment: I'm in a bit of a quandary here. I understand the resolve part now. But it requires that the function it is depending on returns a promise.

My predicament is this: ZMDataModel has two functions like so:

isMonitorsLoaded: function() {
            return monitorsLoaded;
        },
        setMonitorsLoaded: function(loaded) {
            console.log ("ZMData.setMonitorsLoaded="+loaded);
            monitorsLoaded = loaded;
        }
isMonitorsLoaded just returns a variable. setMonitorsLoaded is called by a different factory when its operation is complete. So how do I make the get fn a promise?

Comment: Here is some updated code. If you see the logs, the promise is working just fine - but it seems route resolve is still not loading controller. Any help? http://pastebin.com/vt3m4Zvp

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$rootScope.$emit('eventName')` which works like a broadcast of events for anyone who is subscribe to them whit `$rootScope.$on('eventName')`:

```
// In your monitor loaded method:
onload: function(){
  //Here you can pass optional information to the listeners
  // for Example an array of monitor or an object
  $rootScope.$emit('MONITORS_LOADED',{
    monitors: getMonitors()   
  });
}

// In your controller:
angular.module('zmApp.controllers').controller('zmApp.MonitorCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, ZMHttpFactory, ZMDataModel) {

  $scope.monitors = [];

  $rootScope.$on('MONITOR_LOADED', function(event, data) {  
    $scope.monitors = data;
    // or 
    // $scope.monitors = ZMDataModel.getMonitors();

    console.log("I GOT " + $scope.monitors);
}

$scope.doRefresh = function() {
  //...
 });
};

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not using a promise which will resolve when your monitor servers is loaded? You can set up your service as:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .service ('ZMDataModel', ['$http', function ($http) {

    function MyServices () {
        var _deferred;
        var _isLoading;
        var me = this;

        this.isLoaded = false;

        this.load = function (reload) {

            if (!_deferred || (!_isLoading && reload)) {
                this.isLoaded = false;
                _deferred = $q.defer();

                _isLoading = true;

                // make your call
                $http ({get : 'http://your-site.com'})
                    .then (
                        function success (rawData) {
                            me.isLoaded = true;
                            // parse your data
                            me.monitors = rawData;

                            _deferred.resolve(me);
                        },
                        function fail (error) {
                            _deferred.reject(error);
                            _deferred = null;

                            if (onFail) {
                                me.monitors = [];
                            }
                        }
                    )
                    .finally (
                        function () {
                            _isLoading = false;
                        }
                    );
            }

            return _deferred.promise;
        };
    }

    return MyServices;

    }
]);
```

Now you can use your service everywhere like this:

angular.module('zmApp.controllers').controller('zmApp.MonitorCtrl', ['$scope', 'ZMDataModel', function($scope, ZMDataModel) {

```
    $scope.monitors = [];


    console.log("***Waiting for Monitors to load before I proceed");
    // I can't do a tight loop waiting for ZMDataModel.isMonitorsLoaded
    // so some timeout?

    ZMDataModel.load ().then (
        function (response) {
            $scope.monitors = ZMDataModel.monitors;
        }
    );

    $scope.doRefresh = function() {
        console.log("***Pull to Refresh");
        $scope.monitors = [];
        ZMDataModel.load (true).then (
            function (response) {
                $scope.monitors = ZMDataModel.monitors;
            }
        );
    };

}]);
```

It doesn't matter if an other controller loads the service first. As long as you use the load function without the 'refresh' flag set to true, the service won't load again

Comment: Hello Stefan, I am in the middle of trying to construct the promise and attach it to routes resolve. If you have time, please take a look at my comment above in response to John Stewart. If it does not work, I'll dive into your method. In the mean time if you can take a look at what might be the problem with my approach, I'd much appreciate it (the latest code fragment is at http://pastebin.com/vt3m4Zvp)

Comment: Using states with resolves object is absolute a good idea. You could still write your service as I suggested. In you state you could write:  .state('myState', {
 url: '/monitors',
 templateUrl: 'monitors.html',
    controller: 'monitors-controller',
 resolve : {
  loadedZMDataModel : ['ZMDataModel', function (ZMDataModel)
  {
   return ZMDataModel.load();
  }]
    }
})

Comment: Ah, I solved the problem. I had to move out the deferred variable out of the function - works great now.  I think what was happening earlier was it was getting called with different instances of deferred. Stefan, thanks for looking - I'll now start optimizing it per your suggestions too.

Comment: Okay, I've made a holy mess of my states. Stefan your response looks comprehensive. I'm going to reset, relook, and take a look tomorrow at my code and try and follow your advice in your answer above. I'll post followups as I work my way through your suggestion

Comment: Stefan, what is the logic of using  MyServices? My ZMDataModel service has multiple functions inside it. It is of the format return { function1:function() {..}, function2:function() {...} etc };

Comment: The function 'MyService' is a class that will be instantiated and returned by Angular the first time you inject the 'ZMDataModel'. When you use a service in Angular, Angular returns the return value with 'new' -> return value is 'new MyService () '. The function 'this.load' is a public method in this the class 'MyService'. You could also create an object with the functions and return this instead of a function.

Comment: Hi Stefan, I'm trying to clean up my promise. I've posted it as a new Q as SO doesn't seem to offer a mechanism to keep updating code to one question in a clean way. I still haven't embarked on your method - but if you have the time and look at where I am, I'd much appreciate it in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29627106/the-promise-of-a-promise-again-angular-js