# The promise of a promise again (Angular JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

**Updated with HTTP and initial code based on requests/Please look at the bottom of the post:**

I've been posting several questions on my AngularJS learning curve of late and the SO community has been fantastic. I've been a traditional C programmer when I used to program and have recently started writing my own ionic/Angular JS app. I'm struggling with the promise version of traditional async calls when it comes to converting a custom function to a promise. I don't think I really understood and I find various examples very contrived. I'd appreciate some help. I have some code which is not working, and I have some conceptual questions:

Let's take this simple function:

```
angular.module('zmApp.controllers').service('ZMDataModel', function() { return { getMonitors: function () { return monitors; } }
```

getMonitors is a simple function that basically returns an array of monitors. But here is the rub: When the app first starts, I call an http factory that does an http get and goes about populating this monitor list. This http factory is different from this service but invokes a setMonitor method in this service to populate the array. When the array is populated, a variable called 'monitorsLoaded' is set to 1. When this variable is set to 1, I know for sure monitors is loaded.

Now, I have a view with a controller called "MontageCtrl". I want to wait for the monitors to load before I show the view. In a previous post, one person suggested I use route resolve, but I had to first convert my getMonitors to a promise. So here is what I did:

```
angular.module('zmApp.controllers').service('ZMDataModel',  function($q) {
getMonitors: function () {

            var _deferred  = $q.defer();
            if (monitorsLoaded!=0)
            {
                console.log ("**** RETURNING MONITORS *****");
                    _deferred.resolve(monitors);
            }
            console.log ("*** RETURNING PROMISE ***");
            return _deferred.promise;
        },
```

Next up, in app.js I connected the route as follows:

```html
 .state('app.montage', {
               data: {requireLogin:false},
            resolve: {
                        message: function(ZMDataModel) 
                        {
                            console.log ("Inside app.montage resolve");
                          return ZMDataModel.getMonitors();
                        }
            },
```

Finally I modified my controller to grab the  promise as such:

```html
angular.module('zmApp.controllers').controller('zmApp.MontageCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope, ZMHttpFactory, ZMDataModel,message) {
        
            //var monsize =3;
            console.log ("********* Inside Montage Ctrl");
```

It seems based on logs, I never go inside Montage Ctrl. Route resolve seems to be waiting for ever, whereas my logs are showing that after a while, monitorLoaded is being set to 1.

**I have several conceptual questions:**

a) In function getMonitors, which I crafted as per examples, why do people return a _deferred.promise but only assign a _deferred.resolve? (i.e. why not return it too?). Does it automatically return?

b) I noticed that if I moved var _deferred definition to my service and out of its sub function, it did work, but the next view that had the same route dependency did not. I'm very confused.

c) Finally I ready somewhere that there is a distinction between a service and a factory when it comes to route resolve as a service is only instantiated once. I am also very confused as in some route resolve examples people use when, and I am using .state.
At this stage, I'm deep into my own confusion. Can someone help clarify? All I really want is for various views to wait till monitorsLoaded is 1. And I want to do it via route resolves and promises, so I get the hang of promises once and for all.

**Added:** Here is the HTTP factory code as well as the app.run code that calls this when the app first starts. FYI, the http factory works well - the problems started when I crafted ZMDataModel - I wanted this to be a central data repository for all controllers to use -- so they did not have to call HTTP Factory each time to access data, and I could control when HTTP factory needs to be called

```html
angular.module('zmApp.controllers').factory('ZMHttpFactory', ['$http', '$rootScope','$ionicLoading', '$ionicPopup','$timeout','ZMDataModel',
  function($http, $rootScope, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, $timeout,ZMDataModel) {



    return {
      getMonitors: function() {
                                             
        var monitors = [];
        var apiurl = ZMDataModel.getLogin().apiurl;
        var myurl = apiurl+"/monitors.json";
        
        return $http({
          url: myurl,
          method: 'get'
                  
        }) //http
        .then(function(response) {
              var data = response.data;
              //console.log("****YAY" + JSON.stringify(data));
          // $rootScope.$broadcast ('handleZoneMinderMonitorsUpdate',monitors);
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            
            ZMDataModel.setMonitors(data.monitors);
            ZMDataModel.setMonitorsLoaded(1);
            //monitors = data.monitors;
            return ZMDataModel.getMonitors();
            },
            function (result)
            {
                console.log ("**** Error in HTTP");
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                ZMDataModel.setMonitorsLoaded(1);
                //$ionicPopup.alert ({title: "Error", template:"Error retrieving Monitors. \nPlease check if your Settings are correct. "});
                return  ZMDataModel.getMonitors();
            }
        ); //then
      }, //getMonitors
```

And here is the code in app.run that first calls this:

```html
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup, $rootScope, $state,ZMDataModel, ZMHttpFactory)
{
    
    ZMDataModel.init();
    var loginData = ZMDataModel.getLogin();
    
        if ( loginData.username && loginData.password && loginData.url && loginData.apiurl)
            {
                console.log ("VALID CREDENTIALS. Grabbing Monitors");
                // this calls http factory getMonitors that eventually populated the ZMDataModel 
                // monitors array and sets monitorsLoaded to 1
                ZMHttpFactory.getMonitors();
               
            }
}
```

Comment: In your promise-d version of `getMonitors`, I don't see the http stuff.

Comment: First off, it took me quite a while to get the hang of promises, you're on the right track! Since you're using AngularJS I'd recommend reading up on [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). Second off, could you add your `$http` code? In the current implementation, where does `monitorsLoaded' come from?

Comment: Hi, I've added the HTTP code. That http factory works very well - the problems started with my trying to make ZMDataModel. Previously, all controllers that needed data were calling HTTPFactory directly, which always worked, but was not a good idea - I wanted to reduce calls to HTTP and use ZMDataModel to serve the data.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved all the problems. There were various issues with my initial attempts. My final resolved solution is here [Am I returning this promise correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635884/am-i-returning-this-promise-correctly)

The learnings:

a) Separating the HTTP get into a factory and the data model into another service was unnecessarily complicating life. But that separation was not the problem. Infact, the way the promise was coded above, on first run, if monitorsLoaded was 0, it would simply return the deferred promise and there was no ".success" or similar construct for me to get into the resolve code block again.

b) The biggest thing that was making me run around in loops was deferring or rejecting was simply setting a state. the return always has to be the promise - and it would return the state you set. I assumed return d.promise always means returning "in progress".