# Am I returning this promise correctly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function, getMonitors inside a service. getMonitors returns a list of monitor objects. If the monitor object is empty, it grabs the monitors via http and stores the objects in a monitor object array and then returns it. The function is coded as a promise. I know http returns a promise, but my function may or may not use http - so I've overlaid it with my own promise (see below for code)

Controllers can call getMonitors(0) or getMonitors(1). 0 means if its already loaded in the monitors array due to a previous call, don't load it again. (1) means force reload the array from HTTP

The service and associated getMonitors is coded the following way:

```js
angular.module('zmApp.controllers').service('ZMDataModel', ['$http', '$q',
      function($http, $q) {
        // var deferred='';
        var monitorsLoaded = 0;
        var monitors = [];

        getMonitors: function(forceReload) {
          console.log("** Inside ZMData getMonitors with forceReload=" + forceReload);
          var d = $q.defer();
          if ((monitorsLoaded == 0) || (forceReload == 1)) // monitors are empty or force reload
          {
            console.log("ZMDataModel: Invoking HTTP Factory to load monitors");
            var apiurl = loginData.apiurl;
            var myurl = apiurl + "/monitors.json";
            $http.get(myurl)
              .success(function(data) {
                // console.log ("HTTP success got " + JSON.stringify(data));
                monitors = data.monitors;
                console.log("promise resolved inside HTTP success");
                monitorsLoaded = 1;
                return d.resolve(monitors);
              })
              .error(function(err) {
                console.log("HTTP Error " + err);
                monitors = [];
                console.log("promise resolved inside HTTP fail");
                // I know I need to reject here, not resolve. I'll get to it. For now lets assume I need an empty monitors list if there was an error
                return d.resolve(monitors);
              });
            console.log("promise deferred inside HTTP inside getMonitors");
            return d.promise;

          } else // monitors are loaded
          {
            console.log("Returning pre-loaded list of " + monitors.length + " monitors");
            return d.resolve(monitors);
          }

        },
```

I have a route set up with getMonitors as a dependency like so:

```js
.state('app.montage', {
  data: {
    requireLogin: false
  },
  resolve: {
    message: function(ZMDataModel) {
      console.log("Inside app.montage resolve");
      return ZMDataModel.getMonitors(0);
    }
  },
  url: "/montage",
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: "templates/montage.html",
      controller: 'zmApp.MontageCtrl',

    }
  }
})
```

A sample controller that uses this is coded like so:

```js
angular.module('zmApp.controllers').controller('zmApp.MontageCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, ZMDataModel, message) {

  $scope.monitors = [];
  console.log("Inside MontageCtrl waiting for monitors to load...");

  $scope.monitors = message;
  // this line returns undefined when getMonitors tries to return a preloaded monitor list
  console.log("I have received the monitors inside Montage and there are " + $scope.monitors.length);
  // console.log("***CALLING FACTORY");
  //ZMHttpFactory.getMonitors().then(function(data) //{
  //                                  $scope.monitors = data;
  // console.log("I GOT " + $scope.monitors);
  //    });

  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    console.log("***Pull to Refresh");
    $scope.monitors = [];

    var refresh = ZMDataModel.getMonitors(1);
    refresh.then(function(data) {
      $scope.monitors = data;
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    });

  };
});
```

The problem I am facing is that the first time this is run, the monitors list is empty so ZMData loads the monitors from the HTTP url and the view shows perfectly. When I switch to another view and back to this view, I see it logs that ZMData is returning the preloaded list of monitors (I know they are populated because I am printing out the count in ZMData getMonitor else section). However, what is being returned to the controller is undefined when the "else" part of getMonitors hit.

This likely means I am not returning the promise correctly in getMonitors "else" part.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Don't put your angular JS into "code snippets" like this. They won't run, anyway. The feature is for html/js/css **runnable** snippets.

Comment: I know, but I can't help it. If I use a code block, SO complains about indentation - but it looks fine in my editor. Is that why you dowvoted this Q?

Comment: Complains about indentation - exactly how? Code blocks are supposed to be indented by 4 spaces.

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine, btw.

Comment: Okay, well whoever down voted did not care to explain. I've converted them to code samples. Hope you can put in your answer if you have the time

Comment: Going to bed now. Maybe tomorrow :)

Comment: `getMonitors: function(forceReload) {` looks like a syntax mistake.

Comment: You probably want `return d.resolve(monitors).promise` as well.

Comment: Hi Bergi, yes that was it - this promise stuff has been driving me mad for the past 3 days. I failed to understand that return d.promise was returning the promise and d.reject and d.resolve were changing state. So irrespective of state, the return should always be d.promise after the state has been set. I'm drinking a double scotch shot tonight in celebration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I finally wrapped my head around promises. 
We can't return d.resolve(). That just sets a state. You always need to return d.promise and it if was resolved, it will return the resolve. Man. This drove me mad.I think I finally got the basic hang of promises after 3 different SO questions. I wish tutorials made this clearer. Everyone was only returning d.promise and no one really explained clearly that d.promise returns the state of the promise - which is changed by resolve or reject.

The correct code is:

```
getMonitors: function (forceReload) {
            console.log ("** Inside ZMData getMonitors with forceReload="+forceReload);
            var d = $q.defer();
           if ((monitorsLoaded == 0) || (forceReload == 1)) // monitors are empty or force reload
           {
               console.log ("ZMDataModel: Invoking HTTP Factory to load monitors");
                var apiurl = loginData.apiurl;
                var myurl = apiurl+"/monitors.json";
                $http.get(myurl)
                    .success(function(data)
                    {
                       // console.log ("HTTP success got " + JSON.stringify(data));
                        monitors = data.monitors;
                        console.log ("promise resolved inside HTTP success");
                        monitorsLoaded = 1;
                        d.resolve(monitors);
                    })
                    .error (function (err)
                    {
                        console.log ("HTTP Error " + err);
                        monitors = [];
                        console.log ("promise resolved inside HTTP fail");
                        d.resolve (monitors);
                });
                return d.promise;

           }
            else // monitors are loaded
            {
                console.log ("Returning pre-loaded list of "+monitors.length+" monitors");
                 d.resolve(monitors);
                return d.promise;
            }

        }
```